# Returned element not changing on button click in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that toggles a boolean when a button is clicked. It also successfully console logs the correct message when the button is clicked. But, it does not change the h2 element being returned. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I research so far only brings up situations regarding state. Thank you.

```
function Heading() {
  let darkModeOn = false;
  const darkMode = <h2>Dark mode is on.</h2>;
  const lightMode = <h2>Light mode is on.</h2>;
  const handleMode = () => {
    darkModeOn = !darkModeOn;
    if (darkModeOn) {
      console.log("Darkmode is on.");
    } else {
      console.log("Lightmode is on.");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {darkModeOn ? darkMode : lightMode}
      <button onClick={handleMode}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Heading;

/// Updated code with the below that uses useState hook

import { useState } from "react";

const Mode = () => {
  const [darkModeOn, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  let mode = "";
  const handleMode = () => {
    console.log("button clicked...");
    setDarkMode(!darkModeOn);
    if (darkModeOn) {
      mode = "Dark mode";
    } else {
      mode = "Light mode";
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{mode} is on.</h2>
      <button onClick={handleMode}>Click to change mode.</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Mode;
```

Comment: hi is it giving any errors in the console?

Comment: *Why does this happen and how can I fix it?* - Your question does not include any code showing how you're attempting this, so how can we help?

Comment: Added code. Sorry. I thought I had pasted it.

Comment: You need state to do what you're trying to do. The purpose of state is to persist values across renders - which is what your `darkModeOn` variable is trying and failing to do. Look into `useState` and replace your `let` with state

Comment: I included code below the old one using the useState hook. I am able to console log when button clicked but still text does not change. Can you provide some more hints as to how I can leverage useState to make this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please do it like the below:

```
const Mode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');
  const handleMode = () => {
    console.log("button clicked...");
    if (mode === 'light') setMode('dark')
    else setMode('light')
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{mode} is on.</h2>
      <button onClick={handleMode}>Click to change mode.</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

You should use `useState` to force rerender the component with the new state.
the way you did doesn't trigger the component rerender.

More info:
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Mode = () => {
  const [darkModeOn, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const handleMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkModeOn);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{darkModeOn ? "Dark Mode" : "Light Mode"} is on.</h2>
      <button onClick={handleMode}>Click to change mode.</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Mode;
```

Or, you can also use the following code, where `mode` is also a state variable.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Mode = () => {
  const [darkModeOn, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("Light Mode");
  const handleMode = () => {
    console.log("button clicked...");
    // this means that currently `darkModeOn` is true so we must convert it to Light mode
    if (darkModeOn) {
      setMode"Light mode");
    } else {
      setMode("Dark mode");
    }
    setDarkMode(!darkModeOn);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{mode} is on.</h2>
      <button onClick={handleMode}>Click to change mode.</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Mode;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues in the code.

**The first :**

You are expecting `darkModeOn` to be updated immediately after `setDarkMode(!darkModeOn)` so just after this line you do this :

```js
if (darkModeOn) {
      mode = "Dark mode";
 } else {
     mode = "Light mode"
 }
```

but, again, this is not how react works, when you run a code to update a state, only when this code finishes execting the component rerenders and only then, the state will be updated, so at the moment the `if` statement is executed the new value of `darkModeOn` is not available yet  (because the component didn't rerendered yet).

**The second:**

As it is said, when you updae a state like you are doing inside the `handleMode` function the component rerenders and in this new render `mode` will be initilized again to `''` so doing so is really useless, you don't even need this `mode` variable.

You can simply display inside your JSX based on the value of `darkModeOn`

```js
//...
const handleMode = () => {
  console.log("button clicked...");
  setDarkMode(!darkModeOn);
};
//....
return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleMode}>Click to change mode.</button>
      {darkModeOn ? <div>we are in the dark mode </div> : <div> we are in the light  mode </div>}
    </>
 );
```